# In ArcMap, how much is a Zoom Out click

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, scale

In ArcMap, when I zoom out (or in) a single mouse-click (not dragging a rectangle, just a click), what is the change to the ratio?

If it is different between coordinate systems please explain it on GCS_WGS_1984.

Comment: In mine it goes 1:100, 1:125, 1:150, 1:200, 1:250, 1:300, 1:400, 1:500, 1:600, 1:800, 1:1000, 1:1250, 1:1500, 1:2000, so it appears to be pre-defined scales rather than a specific or percentage change in scale.